# Module Localization in DNN

Tags: localization, internationalization, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I don't know much about the localization process in DNN. The question is that how can you localize a new module?

Is it possible to include localization files with every module separately? What solutions can you come up with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localization of a module is pretty easy thanks to DotNetNuke.

Wherever your .ascx (View) file is, the App_LocalResources folder should always accompany it, on the same level. There should also be a corresponding .ascx.resx file in that folder.

```
view.ascx
App_LocalResources
- view.ascx.resx
```

Once you have that structure in your module. DNN will pick the file up immediately.

To use that resource strings in the resx. Simple tack on the ResourceKey property to the end of your asp controls. e.g.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblExample" runat="server" ResourceKey="lblExample" />
```

You should have a `lblExample.Text` in your resx file which matches up with that label. Note that it adds `.Text` to it automatically.

If it's not showing up, there are a few things to check

1. `LocalResourceFile` property in code. What location is it pointing to?
2. set `ShowMissingKeys=true` in web.config and you'll see what resource strings you're missing.

Comment: I would also add that you can use `DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.LocalizeString("YourKeyName.Text")` to pull in a localized resource into your code. This is also useful on the ASCX end in a code nugget for when you want a piece of localized text but dont want to use a control. Example: `<%=LocalizeString("YourKeyName.Text")%>`

Answer (score 1):

Please find [this document](http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.dotnetnuke.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=jc55aUPEdI8%253D&tabid=478&mid=857&rct=j&q=dnn%20module%20localization&ei=7pu6TYHdKsSZOoGblPIF&usg=AFQjCNHGt2uJmoCjwO4sIRIuCA0dr4QJBA&sig2=H9GPzIYpZUj7hEaUG8ZoHg&cad=rja). I am not sure if it covers your questions and how localizing DotNetNuke modules is different from other Asp.Net applications but please try it out.
If I may suggest something, I would add more tags in the future (like C# for example), it will be visible to broader audience which may result in better answers.

Comment: I had already checked that out and found nothing useful for this case. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a folder called "App_LocalResources" on the same level as your .ascx view files in your project. For each file that you want localized, simply add a .resx file with the same name as the view (including the .ascx extension).

Resx Name Example:

"View.ascx.resx"

Using localistion is really easy after that. Simply set the Resource Key property of whichever controls you want to pull from your resx file to a meaningful name

Example:

```
<dnn:Label id="lblName" ResourceKey="lblName" runat="server" />
```

Resx File:

"lblName.Text" will assign to the Text property of the label
"lblName.Help" will assign to the DNN Tooltip property if you are using dnn:Labels like above

If you want to start using DNN Labels simply put this tag at the top of your page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Label" Src="~/controls/LabelControl.ascx" %>
```

Another handy method available is:

```
LocalizeString("key")
```

It will pull from your resource file and it quite handy when working with things like email templates.