# is the .TEXT necessary in the RESX files

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, dotnetnuke, resx

for a client solution, we are building a structure of RESOURCE files following the RESX standard (or trying to) in an app based on Node

in the specifications we do not see any usage of labels ending with .text, while in the system all resources looks like:

```
<data name="lbl_HelloWorld.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>HELL WORLD!!</value>
</data>
```

**is that .text necessary?**

**is something specific to our client actual system ?** (by the way, it is a DNN / DotNetNuke implementation)

example of posts where it is told about the .text thing:

- [Module Localization in DNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829799/module-localization-in-dnn)

while in the Microsoft pages nothing is told about the .Text thing:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: more links talking about the .txt thing:

Comment: https://www.dnncreative.com/Forum/tabid/88/aft/23954/%5BLink%5D

Comment: http://www.plumco.com.au/DesktopModules/XModPro/help/Localization.html

Comment: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155246/module-development-in-dnn-8-4--localization-support-for-mvc-modules

Comment: Your first link has [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26970241/215552) which says, "*"lblName.Text" will assign to the Text property of the label "lblName.Help" will assign to the DNN Tooltip property if you are using dnn:Labels like above*"

Comment: DNN's localization is a different process than standard .NET localization.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thanks, that i got, that for DNN the .Text thing in the RESX goes to the Text property. The thing is, that's only for DNN, nothing like a standard on .net / asp / etc.. (seems to be from ChrisHammond response)

Comment: @ChrisHammond thanks, therefore, this is just a DNN thing, isnt' it?. While I found useful or interesting, I see it as a unconventional way of play with the RESX, may I ask why that in DNN ? (I believe you are on the developers team of DNN, isn't it?

Comment: I am not one of the developers, used to work for the company, but that was many moons ago

Answer (score 0):

.Text is the text property of the label objectn
[msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d.aspx)

Comment: Thnakas @mattz-reckewg, I got the .Text property in .net, 
But i am talking about the .text "ending" on the RESX files, 
seems to be an unconventional way of using the RESX files to be align to .net properties ??